# DIV container is not hideable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and Javascript and therefore im testing it. I want to create a div container which is draggable and hideable/visible by clicking on a button. 
Could someone please tell why my buttons are not working? Could you also tell me how I can set the div container to invisible as standard so that I have to klick on the show button the see it?

CSS

```
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

HTML

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("draggable").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("draggable").show();
    });
});
```

Here you can see my current code running: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tdsdu1uq/2/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add a `#` to `$("draggable")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply have made a mistake in the jQuery selectors.
You should have written the following :

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#draggable").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#draggable").show();
});
```

Note the '#' for the id. Your update JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdsdu1uq/4/).

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Could you also tell me how to set the div container invisible as standard?

Comment: The call to the hide() function will simply set the following css property: display:none; . So this is a standard. You can also set the css property directly without calling hide() with the following HTML : <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="display: none;"> ... </div>

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("draggable").hide();`

to

```
$("#draggable").hide();
```

and `$("draggable").show();`

to

```
$("#draggable").show();
```

See Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdsdu1uq/3/)